# Can you unpackage a signed APK?

Tags: android, apk

We are considering releasing an internal app onto the play store to make updating and management a bit easier.

We are happy with the security on the app but are concerned about someone unpacking our signed app and gaining access to the source code which contains some api links we don't want shared publicly.

Can this be done? Is there more we can do to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing your apk is required to prevent not authorized person to upload new apk to store. It's not about protecting your sources mostly. If you want more protection - use proguard or other tools to obfuscate your code. Small tutorial on proguard can be found here, for example: https://medium.com/@jonfinerty/beginner-to-proguard-b3327ff3a831

Comment: Is proguard somethign you put the app through>

Comment: It's a tool, embedded in android studio. You should create a config for it (rules) and turn it on in your build.gradle.

Comment: Added link with more explanation on proguard and example.